# Angular 7 with json-server - how do you retrieve the id returned in a post response?

Tags: angular, post, httpresponse, json-server

Using the following http options:

```
const httpOptions: any = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),
  observe: 'response'
};
```

am sending an http post to a json-server endpoint as follows:

```
return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/events`, myEvent, httpOptions);
```

The code that subscribes to the post is as follows:

```
this.api.saveEvent(this.event).subscribe(data => {
  // Need to pick up the id from data (HttpResponse) here
});
```

[image: This is the returned HttpResponse object]

I can see that `data` returned in the subscription is of type `HttpResponse` - what's the correct way to cast `data` so that I can get to the `body` property of the response and pick up the `id` property returned by json-server?

**Update**: as per comments below, I eventually got the `saveNewEvent` method to return `Observable<HttpRespponse<Event>>`, however this only works if I pass the http options as an inline anonymous object. Setting up the options in a const and referencing that const in the post method does not work, and I haven't figured out why. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please post the actual response from the server, so we can see the return data the needs to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

when you specify the type you can get the data, just make sure your API returns it correctly.

```
return this.http.post<{id: Number}>(`${this.baseUrl}/events`, myEvent, httpOptions);

this.api.saveEvent(this.event).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data.id);
});
```

Comment: Tried this and it results in a compilation error: `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'` - do you also need to cast `data` in the subscription?

Comment: Made some progress - if I call the post method with an inline anonymous type for the options:

`return this.http.post<Event>('${this.baseUrl}/events', event, { observe: 'response'});`

then I can return `Observable<HttpResponse<Event>>` from my api service and my component can access `data.body.id` when subscribing to the response.

Comment: However, if I set options in a const anonymous type like this:

`const options: any = {
  observe: 'response'
};`

And then call the post method: `return this.http.post<Event>('${this.baseUrl}/events', event, options);`

then I get `Type 'HttpEvent<Event>' is not assignable to type 'HttpResponse<Event>'.`

So what's the difference in how you pass options?

Comment: In my example,  the response from the server would be a JSON response something like { "id": 123 }.   by setting type to as above. it will automatically map to json to the object/id.   for me  you can also remove the `observe: 'response'` statement.   According to me mix concepts from angular and nodejs (in nodejs you work with req and body when handling json).

Comment: The `httpclient.post()` method is returning an instance of `HttpResponse`, which has a body property. This is an Angular class - how do you see this as mixing Angular and Node?

Comment: @JTIsALeaf you are right, I didn't check the doc, since I never had a need for it.